# Trying to get name of Reviewer from Product Review Eloquent in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In **Product.php**

```
public function reviews(){
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

In **Review.php**

```
public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In **User.php**

```
public function reviews(){
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class);
}
```

in controller

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $request->slug)->with('category')->with('reviews.user')->first();
```

in Blade

```
{{$review->user->name}}
```

Now In blade it returns null.

mention that
review table has product_id, reviewed_by

Now, How Can I get Reviewers Name from this relationship Models? Please Help me with this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You need to specify foreign keys on both hasMany and belongsTo relations if you have different foreign keys other than laravel's default alphabetical order**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'reviewed_by');
}

//In User Model
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class,'reviewed_by');
}

//In Product Model
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Review::class,'product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

first, you should fix you relationship:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'reviewed_by');
}
```

you can ignore second argument only if you follow the convention (if your column name is user_id, not  reviewed_by)

then in your controller:

```
$product = Product::where('slug', $request->slug)->with(['category','reviews'=>function($query){
$query->with('user');}])->first();
```

Comment: For my own curiosity, what is the reasoning behind 'reviews'=>function($query){
$query->with('user');} instead of dot notation like: reviews.user?

Comment: after fixing the relation it should work either way, i only choose this because it is more clear

Comment: Cool,  was just wondering if it was something deeper than preference.

Comment: with('reviews.user') and this one is same i think.

Comment: just using belongsTo ('foreign') is not enough for this. I have to add hasMany('foreign').
then It works.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the foreign key to use for user, since it is not stored as user_id. Like so:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'reviewed_by');
}
```

Comment: Ok, and you are sure the db has the user relation stored in it properly? Because if reviewed_by is on reviews table, this is correct.

Comment: yes. I also have to add foreign key on user.php, hasMany('foreign'). than It works. Thanks for your time.